# C++ Properly deallocate multidimensional array with underlying contiguous memory

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, memory-management, new-operator, delete-operator

I have a function which allocates memory for a 3d array. The goal is for the memory to be guaranteed contiguous but also have the convenience of `a[k][j][i]` syntax:

```
double *** allocate_3d(const int& sz, const int& sy, const int& sx){
    double * aMem = new double[sz*sy*sx];
    double *** array = new double**[sz];
    for(int k=0; k<sz; k++){
        array[k] = new double*[sy];
        for(int j=0; j<sy; j++){
            array[k][j]= aMem + k*sy*sx + j*sx;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Supposing that I call the function like this

```
x   = allocate_3d(wdz,wdy,wdx);
```

How can I properly deallocate x? I tried the following:

```
void delete_3d(double *** array, const int& sz, const int& sy, const int& sx){
    for(int k=0; k<sz; k++){    
        for(int j=0; j<sy; j++){
            delete[] array[k][j];
        }
        delete[] array[k];
    }
    delete[] array;
}
```

But running Valgrind gives an error and seems to indicate that the memory is not deallocated properly.

Comment: Avoid the entire headache, and use `std::vector` to allocate and properly deallocate all memory for you. Nothing written above requires explicit `new` and `delete`. A vector will do everything for you. That's what a vector is for.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think I can get the syntax `a[k][j][i]` and have contiguous memory if I use a vector of vector of vectors.

Comment: Every dynamically allocated object, above, can be replaced with an equivalent vector. Both `aMem`, and `array` can simply be vectors. The End.

Comment: Yes, but they are not guaranteed contiguous. I need the memory to be contiguous.

Comment: A vector guarantees contiguous memory.

Comment: @EternusVia the jagged array you currently have is anything but contiguous.

Comment: Yes, but `aMem` is continuous, which is what I need.

Comment: In the future, I will be sure to use vectors. For now, I would still really love to know how to deallocate this array, just so I can better understand the `new` and `delete` operators. I am not sure if I need to preserve the pointer `aMem` so that I can `delete` it later?

Comment: @EternusVia `array[0][0]` gives you `aMem`.

Comment: @EternusVia my bad, I overlooked that you were actually allocating this pointer structure to point into one large underlying array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should actually be like this:

```
void delete_3d(double *** array, const int& sz, const int& sy, const int& sx) {
    // first, restore the pointer to the actual aMem
    double * aMem = array[0][0];
    // only one dimension was allocated in the loop,
    // so only one loop should be deallocating things
    for(int k = 0; k < sz; k++) {
        delete [] array[k];
    }
    delete[] array;
    delete[] aMem;
}
```

---

### A way-better solution

Wrap `std::vector` to get both: contiguous memory and a reasonably simple access syntax and as a bonus no additional arrays which is better for memory, performance and maintenance:

```
class Array3d {
public:
    Array3d(size_t sx, size_t sy, size_t sz)
        : m_sx(sx), m_sy(sy) {
        m_array.resize(sx * sy * sz);
    }

    // Can't overload operator[] with more that one parameter
    // so we'll have to do with operator()
    double &operator()(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z) {
        size_t index = x * m_sx * m_sy + y * m_sy + z;
        return m_array[index];
    }

private:
    size_t m_sx, m_sy;
    std::vector<double> m_array;
};
```

Usage example:

```
Array3d array(3, 3, 3);
array(0, 1, 2) = 3.14;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: @EternusVia, please also consider an alternative solution that I've added.

Comment: Thank you for the additional input. May I ask in what ways it is better for performance to use the class method?

Comment: @EternusVia, a class method will almost definitely be inlined by the compiler if defined in the same translation unit, so there will be no overhead whatsoever. On the other hand, the hierarchy of arrays adds additional indirection on each level and CPUs "don't like" indirections because it's bad for cache performance and also you have to access multiple separate arrays for each element access which is also bad for cache because they can be "all over the place" in the memory.

Comment: Interesting! I was under the impression that since the underlying `aMem` is contiguous, the cache performance would not be so bad. But I guess that's not the case. I will definitely be implementing your solution.

Comment: Considering the class as advertised, saving `m_sz` and using a `std::unique_ptr<double[]>` would be more efficient (saving the unused capacity), though necessitate manually adding copy-ctor/assignment if desired. Also, if all of the dimensions are strictly positive, it might be even better to pre-compute stride for each index. Relaxing that to allow zero-dimensions, and not supporting recovery of dimensions would even allow more layout-flexibility.

Comment: @EternusVia, in any case all these performance considerations are purely theoretical until you actually benchmark your code. You should always measure the performance first and only then optimize if necessary, otherwise you'll be just obsessing about it and making your code more complicated for no reason.